# The action cannot be completed because the file is open in php.exe

Tags: php, windows, batch-file

I am running my batch file and i am executing my php file through batch file,now the php file will create a text file. after, i will terminate my batch file the textfile cannot be renamed or cannot be deleted. it shows this error "The action cannot be completed  because the file is open in php.exe"

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur if you maintain file handles throughout your application. Make sure you are closing the file. Without seeing your PHP code I can't give you a better answer than that.